# Numpy.ndarray object is not callable error reason

Tags: python, kalman-filter

I am implementing unscented kalman filter and getting this error "numpy.ndarray object is not callable" for the non-linear function 'g' in the prediction step.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZMP1e.jpg)

I have also attached my code where I got this error. Any assistance would be highly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Can you please add your code so one can recreate the issue?

Comment: Yes sure, Please check the code below:
        gx = np.array([g_E, g_R])    
        
        Q = np.diag([0.1,0.1,0.1,0.1,0.1,0.1]) # process noise covariance
        
        self.sigmas_x = np.zeros((self.M,2*self.M + 1))
        
        for i in range(2*self.M + 1):
            
            self.sigmas_x[:,i] = gx(self.sigmas[:,i],dt, u)
g_E and g_R are arrays with values and the main code in which I called this is as below:
for step in range(NUM_STEPS):
    
    kf.predict(dt=DT, u =np.array([sigma_f, V_x, V_dot_x]))
Kindly guide me in finding the error.

Comment: @jawaria Please put your code in your answer as a codeblock; it is almost impossible to read your code in a comment.

Comment: Code is added to the codeblock, can you please suggest the possible solution. Thanks

Comment: There is still a lot of missing information: In what line does the error occur? How is `kf` defined? How is `dt`, `DT`, `sigma_f`, `V_x`,... defined? With out this missing code information one can only take guesses.

Comment: Please, have a read here: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Thank you for your feedback, actually, the original code is too long that is wht I added only the part which contains the error. However, dt and DT are the time step 0.1 for the given case, V_x velocity, V_dot_x acceleration, sigma_f wheel angle are single random number

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just like the error message says, `gx` is a numpy array:

```
gx = np.array([g_E, g_R])
```

But you are trying to call it as if it were a function:

```
self.sigmas_x[:,i] = gx(self.sigmas[:,i],dt, u)
```

Hence the error.

Comment: Thank you for your feedback. You are right, this is the error but I am not sure how to remove it as I added it in function definition but it gives error. I must also mention that g_E and g_R are very long equations which are then merged together in gx as gx =[g_E, g_R]. The error message which I got is: 
'builtin_function_or_method' object is not subscriptable'

Comment: Well, you can ask a new question about the new error, or more generally "How to do X in Python".